# AOP learning resources

Tags: aop

I'm new to AOP and I was wondering if there is a good reasorce out there that would help me understand where I can use AOP in my projects.

I work mainly in C# but I'm looking for tutorials about practical AOP and not a specific tool (i.e. PostSharp or other) - I'm looking for common practices/patterns (not tools) and usage examples in any language - not just C#/.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far AOP is tied to frameworks, so you should read the documentation of the AOP framework rather then general approach.

But we can specify three common types of AOP:

1. pre code injection (in the code file) [code generators that work pior the pre compilation]
2. runtime code injection (inject, swamp pointers, in memory) [spring?, my own framework]
3. post code injection [postSharp]

most resources can be found here: "http://csharp-source.net/open-source/aspect-oriented-frameworks"

The most common use is a plugin architecture, logging, caching as well as some domain specific AOP like setting some specific properties on a object that is in a certain domain and state from AOP so that the dev doesn't care about it, other than that presistance layers can use AOP to generate SQL command objects etc.

The thing in AOP is that you need to have a good understanding how the system works if you want to go beyond the common things like Logging, many junior devs don't get AOP so I would be careful with using it in a domain specific way, this will work fine if you are in a strong dev team that has lots of experience with AOP.

EDIT: Here is an good [tutorial](http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html) to spring AOP, Spring is a huge beast, but once you learn it it works very well, the only downside is xml configuration rather then fluent one.